# Number of subsets $S$ of $Z$ that contains $m$ elements and also has the property that $S\bigcap X$ has $n$ elements.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint sets containing $p$ and $q$ elements respectively, and
let the set $Z$ be defined as $Z\bigcup Y$. Find the number of subsets $S$ of $Z$ that contains $m$ elements and also has the property that $S\bigcap X$ has $n$ elements.

What I've tried is:

Total elements in $Z$ is $p+q$, so subsets containing $m$ elements is $C(p+q,m)m!$ where $C$ denotes combination.

How to include $n $ elements interesection ?

Thankyou

Comment: Hint: first choose the $n$ elements of $S$ which are in $X$, and then choose the $m-n$ elements which are in $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct such a subset, we must take $n$ elements fom $X$ and $m-n$ elements from $Y$, so the number of such subsets is

$$\binom{|X|}{n} \cdot \binom{|Y|}{m-n}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!